# Search function listing out not accurate

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Currently i am doing the search function for a application similar to yellow page.

Below is the query i use to get the data.

```
SELECT * 
FROM company_table 
WHERE company_name REGEXP 'Word1|word2' 
    or company_service_tag REGEXP 'Word1|word2'.
```

But this will list out all the companies which not order by % of the accuracy.

Can anyone suggest me, what should i do, or maybe i should not use `"regexp"`.
please consider about the execution time because this will use in a big data.

Comment: did you try like %searchthing%

Comment: @Susandi Susila - please provide some sample data and expected output

Comment: `Regexp` and `like` don't apply weight (% of accuracy). See full text searching. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: What's your formula for "% of the accuracy"?